# Is there a difference in these declarations?

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

Both of these are declaring Jagged Lists correct?

```
//Declare 'Jagged' List
//Version 1
private List<string>[] fieldInfoArray = new List<string>[7];

//Version 2
private List<string>[][] fieldInfoArray = new List<string>[7][];
```

There is no difference between these two declarations right? They are both essentially doing the same thing correct? Declaring a Jagged List?

Comment: you're declaring two completely different objects.  So yes there's a huge difference

Comment: Be more specific. In my code they both seem to be declaring an array of arrays (or a list of lists) however you would like to think of it.

Comment: @Shammy You shouldn't judge the concept based on what the debug shows since the compiler optimizes the code. For example, declare a variable you don't use and set a break point on it. The variable exists but the debugger will never land on it.

Comment: @SILENT When I debug with break points, and hover my mouse over the object at hand, i.e. fieldInfoArray (the first declaration) it has an array with 8 arrays inside of it. So what everyone is saying makes no sense, or they just didn't know that you could declare it this way, OR there is something else really weird going on lol

Comment: @SILENT Of course the debugger will never land on a variable that you don't initialize, why would it? That is completely irrelevant to the debugger telling me that what I in fact have is a LIST of 8 LISTS. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Shammy I created a quick code sample and tested it. I get 7 arrays for new List<string>[7]. Not sure what you're talking about 8 arrays.

Comment: You're correct, I was misunderstanding the concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Both declare arrays. When you will try to access the elements of either array, you will be returned `List<string>`.
- First one is a 1-D array of size 7. All the 7 elements are `List<string>`s.
- The second array is **also a 1-D array** of size 7 but each of those 7 elements is another *"**1-D array** of `List<string>`"* (and not just "`List<string>`").

Comment: Isn't the rectangular array defined as as `Array[3,4]`?

Comment: This is incorrect, my first declaration is definitely not a single array. I can send you a image of it in debug mode, it's an array of arrays. That's why I am very confused.

Comment: @Shammy You shouldn't judge the concept based on what the debug shows since the compiler optimizes the code.

Comment: When I debug with break points, and hover my mouse over the object at hand, i.e. fieldInfoArray (the first declaration) it has an array with 8 arrays inside of it. So what everyone is saying makes no sense, or they just didn't know that you could declare it this way, OR there is something else really weird going on lol

Comment: I think my terminology is wrong ,it has a "List" that holds 8 "Lists".

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: You are correct. I removed that content altogether as the answer was complete without it and more importantly it was wrong. `Array[3,4]` is a Rectangular Array while `Array[3][ ]` as well as `Array[3][4]` are both Jagged Arrays.

Comment: @displayName How would I traverse through "the second case" you have posted such that I only iterate through the first element of my array (i,e, my first list) and then stop iterating. Do you know?

Comment: For example if I had [0] = {"cat","dog","shrump"} and i had [1] = {"other stuff"} I only want to get cat dog and shrimp and then stop. Idk the syntax though via the for loop on how to do that

Comment: @Shammy: You can access the first lists by `fieldInfoArray[i][0]` and varying `i` from 0 to 6.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < fieldInfoArray[0][1].Count; i++) I'm getting a error for this? I'm trying to loop through just the first list then break out

Comment: Ahh I went ahead and posted it, I can't figure it out. I tried that too

Comment: @Shammy about "declaration is definitely not a single array." and "debug show it's as array of arrays". Actually debug shows it as array of lists. List<T> is basically an array. That's why it's so confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<string>[] fieldInfoArray = new List<string>[7];
```

This is declaring an array, of size 7, of `List<string>`.

```
private List<string>[][] fieldInfoArray = new List<string>[7][];
```

This is declaring a two dimensional array of `List<string>`, containing 7 rows of `List<string>` arrays who are yet to be initialized/allocated.

Comment: The second array is a **jagged array**, not a two dimensional array.

Comment: True. I guess I'm in the bad habit of still calling them 2D arrays, since I still think of them as being two dimensional, even though they may not form a perfect 2D square in terms of allocation. :)

Comment: You claim that the first is a single dimensional array, but how sure are you? Have you actually tried it out? In my code it is treating it as a array of arrays.

Comment: Quite sure. It's an array... of `List<String>`s. You are seeing your array of Lists.

Comment: Wait, so you are saying I'm saying my Lists inside of my Lists? How is that possible? Is a List not distinct from a array? I always treated Lists as like vectors

Comment: An array (not to be confused with the `Array` class) is not a List object. It is a pointer to a block of associated memory. You have an array of Lists. There are 7 Lists in this array. Each List **object** has a chain of whatever object is templated. In this case, a string.

Comment: OH! I see, so that's why to me it appears as a Jagged List but in fact this is nothing more than just a Array of Lists correct?

Comment: A lowercase 'array', yes. There is also an object named `Array` that it shouldn't be confused with.

Comment: WOW, I feel like an idiot. Thank you for the clarification , I was so confused.